# Most efficient way to continuously find the median of a stream of numbers (in Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**I'm trying to solve a problem which reads as follows:**

A queue of eager single-digits (your input) are waiting to enter an empty room.

I allow one digit (from the left) to enter the room each minute.

Each time a new digit enters the room I chalk up the median of all the digits currently in the room on the chalkboard. [The median is the middle digit when the digits are arranged in ascending order.]. If there are two median numbers (i.e. two middles) then rather than using the average, I chalk up the lower one of the two.

I chalk new digits to the right of existing digits so my chalkboard number keeps getting longer.

What number ends up on your chalkboard once all the digits are in the room?

Consider the example input: 21423814127333

- 2 (the leftmost) is allowed into the room where it is the only digit so I write 2 on the chalkboard.
- 1 is then allowed into the room to join 2. The smaller one of these two is used as the median so I chalk up 1 to the right of 2 on the chalkboard (my number is now 21)
- 4 now enters the room. The median of 1, 2 and 4 is 2 so I add 2 to my chalkboard (my number is now 212)
- ...this process continues until the final 3 enters the room ... all the numbers are in the room now which, when sorted, are 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,7,8,8. There are two median digits but they are both 3 so I add 3 to my chalkboard and my final number is 21222222222233

**My current solution:**

```
num = input()
new = str(num[0])
whole = [num[0]]

for i in range(1, len(num)):
    whole.append(num[i])
    whole.sort()
    new += whole[i//2]

print(new)
```

The problem is that it takes too long - so it passes 6/10 (hidden) test cases but exceeds the time limit for the other 4. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Rather than sort the whole list each time, you can use a binary search to find the proper insert location.  That will make a HUGE difference when the list gets large.  Python's `bisect` module can help with that.

Comment: Consider taking advantage of the fact that there are only a few possible values in the list. Instead of actually building a list, what if you simply *counted* how many times each digit appeared so far? Can you see how to use math on the digit counts to find the median?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are repeatedly sorting,
with key comparison,
so total cost is O(N * N log N),
that is, it is at least quadratic.

> single-digits (your input) are waiting to enter

The key to this problem is the range limit on input.
We know that each input `x` is in this range:

```
0 <= x < 10
```

Use [counters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).
We can easily allocate ten of them.

Keep a running count of total number of digits that have been
admitted to the room.
Each time you have to report a median, compute
[sum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html)
of ordered counters, stopping when you get
to half the total count.

```
max_val = 10
counter = {i: 0  for i in range(max_val)}
...
assert 0 <= input_val < max_val

counter[input_val] += 1

cum_sum = 0
for i in range(max_val):
    cum_sum += counter[i]
    ...
```

Since median is a robust statistic,
typically there will be some stability
in the median you report, e.g. "2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2".
You can use that to speed the computation
still further, by incrementally computing the
cumulative sum.
It won't change the big-Oh complexity, though,
as there's a constant number of counters.
We're still looking at O(N), since we have to
examine each of the N digits admitted to the room and then report the current median.
This *does* beat the O(N log N) cost of an approach that
relies on bisecting an ordered vector.

Comment: You can optimize by maintaining a cumulative sum of the counters instead of the counters themselves. When N arrives, add 1 to all counters >= N, not just N

Comment: Then you can use the fact that median is robust to start checking from your previous median each time, and decide which half the new median is going to be in if it changed

Answer (score 1):

Since `whole` is already sorted you can use `bisect.insort` to insert new items and keep it sorted:

```py
from bisect import insort
num = input()
new = str(num[0])
whole = [num[0]]

for i in range(1, len(num)):
    insort(whole, num[i])
    new += whole[i//2]

print(new)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you keep a counter per digit (in a list) you actually have the sorted sequence implicitly represented. Then have a "pointer" to the current median: this pointer consists of two components: the median value itself (which is an index in the counter list), and which occurrence of that value really represents the median (an occurrence number).

When a new input digit is processed you can then decide whether this pointer should be updated. It either doesn't, or it moves 1 unit forward or backward in the sorted (implicit) list.

Code:

```
def generatemedians(iterable):
    counter = [0] * 10  # a counter for each digit

    it = map(int, iterable)
    # Process the first entry
    median = next(it, None)
    if median is None:
        return  # No values
    medianidx = 0
    counter[median] = 1
    yield median

    # Process the other entries
    for i, digit in enumerate(it):
        counter[digit] += 1
        if i % 2 == 0:  # the total number of digits becomes even
            if digit < median:  # The median only changes if the digit is inferior
                if medianidx:
                    medianidx -= 1
                else:
                    median -= 1
                    while not counter[median]:
                        median -= 1
                    medianidx = counter[median] - 1
        else:  # the number of digits becomes odd
            if digit >= median:  # The median doesn't change if the digit is inferior
                if medianidx < counter[median] - 1:
                    medianidx += 1
                else:
                    median += 1
                    while not counter[median]:
                        median += 1
                    medianidx = 0
        yield median

# main 
num = input()
print(*generatemedians(num))
```

One iteration of the outer loop takes constant time, even when `median += 1` or `median -= 1` has to execute multiple times, as the range of `median` is 0..9.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a list of cumulative counts of each digit and compute the median by finding the first position that corresponds to at least half the number of digits added so far:

```
def runMed(S):
    cum = [0]*10
    for i,digit in enumerate(map(int,S),1):
        cum[digit:] = (c+1 for c in cum[digit:])
        yield next(m for m,c in enumerate(cum) if c*2>=i)
```

output:

```
S = "21423814127333"
print(*runMed(S))
# 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3
```

Each number will take at most 20 iterations to produce the median, resulting in an O(n) solution.

Comment: When I read your code I expect a NameError; it looks like it references `n` before assignment.

Comment: My bad, changed `n` to `digit` and forgot one `n` trying to make names more meaningful. Fixed now.